# Android Studio: Sliding up/down part of the layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, slide

In my app, i have logs (with a date for each one), I created an activity to be able to display them by date using a Calendar to select the desired date. But the calendar takes up a lot of space, so I want to be able to slide it up (and replace the calendar by just the date) and expand the recycler accordingly just like in the images.

Before

[image: Before]

After

[image: After]

I tried https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel but this sliding panel goes over the recycler instead of pushing down (plus it greys it out when expanded and i don't want that).
So how could i achieve that?

Comment: are you looking for Bottomsheet?
https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomsheet/BottomSheetDialogFragment

You have some customized library like :
https://github.com/trafi/anchor-bottom-sheet-behavior

for your need

Comment: @Kannan_SJD not exactly, I want to drag the calendar up, and the recycler has to expand, I want it to be still 100% accessible even when the calendar is shown. With BottomSheet, parts of the recycler wouldn't be visible until I expand it.

Comment: Have you checked the library I have posted above? it has three states, collapsed anchored and expanded. You have to create a custom bottomsheet behaviour and default your bottomsheet state to anchored. Hope that should serve the purpose. Also you can create a custom cordinator layout behaviour for calendar, so that when you scroll the calendar shrinks upto a postion.
http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator

I will try to work this out with real code.